# Remove tags when upload image using Redactor

Tags: php, html, yii2, strip-tags, redactor

I use yii2 redactor from [here](https://github.com/yiidoc/yii2-redactor).
When I upload an image, it's saved along with html tags.[image]

I want to strip all the tags automatically when upload image/file, so just the image filename saved in database.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You have a separate field to upload thumbnail? I think it is better to use pure Yii2 file-upload implementation then ([here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-file-upload.html))

If you are stubborn enough - you could use RegExp like that:

```
$html = '<p><img border="0" src="/images/image.jpg" alt="Image" width="100" height="100" /><p>';
$result = preg_match('@src="([^"]+)"@' ,$html, $matches);
```

Then in `$matches` array you will find all the occurrences. In your case - it will be just `$matches[0]`